# Ubuntu overrides BIOS boot priority

Tags: boot, usb, windows

I installed Ubuntu server 21.10 on my Windows 7 to make a minecraft server, yet learned that there is a better way to do it without Ubuntu. The person helping recommended I install Windows 10 and remove Ubuntu to make it. I have the Windows 10 ISO file on my USB key and changed the BIOS booting priority so it's number 1. But when I restarted the computer, nothing happened and Ubuntu launched as it would normally. So I went to check the BIOS order, and somehow, even if I saved the modifications before rebooting, ubuntu is on top of the priority list, my USB key number 2. I retried changing the order, putting ubuntu last and making sure I save before exiting, but the same thing keeps happening.

I also tried pressing enter on start up to manually select a boot option, but when I press enter to select my USB key with the Windows 10 ISO, the screen turns black and then loops back the the same boot menu.

Anyone knows how I could fix this ? (trying to install it on Windows 7 ThinkPad)

Comment: It seems like your question is about your firmware boot priority which can vary from model to model. This isn't a part of any operating system. Have you reviewed support or documentation for your particular motherboard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Windows is off topic on this site but I will say why Windows 7? It is not supported any longer by MS.

Comment: @David I learned you can make minecraft servers on old laptops, my old laptop happened to be Windows 7 (also sorry if its off topic)

Answer (score 1):

When your system just skips your preferred option, that usually means that the selected option isn't bootable, which in Your case could mean that You maybe should try to flash the `.iso` to your USB-drive again.

(There guides on how to do it as it isn't as trivial as it is to create a live USB for Linux)

---

Also since this an Ubuntu board, I can only recommend you try to use Ubuntu-Server as a Minecraft server as it uses a lot less resources then Windows, is made to be used as a server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only bootable device is the ubuntu disk, make sure your usb-drive is functional, and tell us how it went!

Comment: If what you say is true it would not cause a black screen as the OP has said.